# No windows authentification to my IIS Server

Tags: windows, authentication, iis-7.5

I'm disappointed. I develop an Intranet. And I put in TestServer (Windows 7 pro/ IIS 7.5). I Put in IIS enable Windows auth. and disabled Anonimous like I read here.
I put in my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
<authorization>
    <allow users="Pro\Yannick" />
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I put in applicationconfig

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
    <providers>
       <add value="Negotiate" />
       <add value="NTLM" />
     </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>
```

When I run my Intranet it's run. I'm connecting and httpcontext identity name return my PC/User name

But The others machines can't access. It's ask me user and password. And when I let anonimous connexion, i've httpcontext identity name empty.
Particularity : there isn't AD, domain, only local user in a WorkGroup.
I'm completely lost. I try and try but nothing change.
I can ping my server and the others pc. I put my server in same WorkGroup...
What else?

Comment: According to what you have there, it looks like you're only allowing yourself access and nobody else.  To test it, try changing to <allow users="*" /> and see if they can log in.  Since you don't have a domain you're probably going to need to set up an account for each user on the server...

Comment: It's not the server connexion it's my laptop connexion. When I put my server, it's good. But not when I put my laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helps me. In fact, I don't create local users on my server. I though that computer send me their name. But it's more complicate. When you haven't AD. You need a safe authority could authentify. In that case, only my server. If you won't have authentify box, you need to create same name account and same password of the local user on computers. Else it's ask name user and password from new accounts server and here you can save it in your browser.